# How to solve This modify Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Every Thing goes right ,I've all the values that make me get the new model with values to modify it but something goes wrong at the final step
and my model validation state is true
This is my post Controller

```
[HttpPost]       
    public ActionResult Edit(Problem problem, HttpPostedFileBase fileUpload)
    {
        Problem Edproblem = db.Problems.Find(problem.Id);
        ViewBag.ATMId = new SelectList(db.ATMs, "Id", "AtmNumber", Edproblem.ATM.AtmNumber);
        ViewBag.UserId = WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name);
        ViewBag.ProblemTypeId = new SelectList(db.ProblemTypes, "Id", "Name", Edproblem.ProblemTypeId);
        var bankId = from e in db.ATMs where e.Id == problem.ATMId select e;
        ViewBag.BankId = new SelectList(db.Banks, "Id", "Name", bankId);
        ViewBag.AreaId = new SelectList(db.Areas, "Id", "Name", db.Areas.Where(p => p.Id == Edproblem.ATM.AreaId));
        ViewBag.GovId = new SelectList(db.Governates, "Id", "Name", Edproblem.ATM.Area.GovernateId);

        Problem beforeEdit = db.Problems.AsNoTracking().First(p => p.Id == problem.Id);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

            if (!Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/UploadImages/" + now.ToString("yyyy_MM/"))))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/UploadImages/" + now.ToString("yyyy_MM/")));
            }
            if (!Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/UploadImages/" + now.ToString("yyyy_MM/") + Edproblem.ATMId.ToString())))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/UploadImages/" + now.ToString("yyyy_MM/") + Edproblem.ATMId.ToString()));
            }
            if (!Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/UploadImages/" + now.ToString("yyyy_MM/") + Edproblem.ATMId.ToString() + now.ToString("/dd/"))))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/UploadImages/" + now.ToString("yyyy_MM/") + Edproblem.ATMId.ToString() + now.ToString("/dd/")));
            }

            var image = WebImage.GetImageFromRequest();

            if (fileUpload != null)
            {
                string fileName = fileUpload.FileName.ToString();
                fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + fileName.Substring(fileName.LastIndexOf("."));
                fileName = now.ToString("yyyy_MM/") + problem.ATMId.ToString() + "/" + now.ToString("dd/") + fileName;
                if (fileUpload != null && fileUpload.ContentLength > 0)
                    fileUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/UploadImages/" + image));

                image.Save(Server.MapPath("/UploadImages/" + fileName));                   

                problem.ImagePath = fileName;
            }
            else
            {                    
                if (problem.ImagePath == null)
                {
                    var getPath = (from e in db.Problems 
                                  where e.Id == problem.Id
                                  select e.ImagePath).ToList();
                    problem.ImagePath = getPath[0].ToString();
                }
            }
            problem.UserId = WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name);                
            db.Entry(problem).State = EntityState.Modified;                
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(problem);
    }
```

This is Error as it appear exactly:

```
An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.
```

Comment: Why do you load a Problem object into variable beforeEdit if you don't plan to use it?

Comment: i was trying something like getting the old value from the exist data stored but fail with no change in error message
you can say useless step

Comment: Can't you populate the beforeEdit with the new data, then save that one instead? Load it without the AsNoTracking(), then populate UserId, imagepath and such.

Comment: Thanks Alot man i made somechanges and it work like what you say exactly

Comment: Great! Summarized a short answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're loading a Problem object into variable beforeEdit, and there is no further use of it.

If you try to update the beforeEdit with the new data from the parameter, and save that one instead of the object returned from the view.